# Multi linechart (primefaces) on one page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, linechart

I'm trying to insert more than one linechart on the same page. For realize that I have the bean's code:

```
public void createChartWithMetrics() {
    this.cartesianChartModel = new ArrayList<CartesianChartModel>();
    ServiceMetricsDAO serviceMetricDAO = new ServiceMetricsDAO();
    List<String> uriEntityList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (TreeNode selectedNode : analyzeMetricMenuTree.getSelectedNodes()) {
        uriEntityList.add(selectedNode.getData().toString());
    }

    this.serviceMetricMap = serviceMetricDAO.getServiceMetricMapByEntityList(uriEntityList, Utility.convertDateToString(DATEFORMAT, dateFrom),
            Utility.convertDateToString(DATEFORMAT, dateTo));

    for (List<List<ServiceMetric>> serviceMetricListList : serviceMetricMap.values()) {
        if(!serviceMetricListList.isEmpty()) {
            this.cartesianChartModel.add(createModelFromList(serviceMetricListList));
        }
    }
}

private CartesianChartModel createModelFromList(final List<List<ServiceMetric>> serviceMetricListList) {
    CartesianChartModel cartesianChart = new CartesianChartModel();
    for (List<ServiceMetric> serviceMetricList : serviceMetricListList) {
        if (!serviceMetricList.isEmpty()) {
            ChartSeries chartSeries = new ChartSeries();
            for (ServiceMetric serviceMetric : serviceMetricList) {
                chartSeries.setLabel(serviceMetric.getDependsOn());
                chartSeries.set(serviceMetric.getAtTime(), serviceMetric.getHasMetricValue());
            }
            cartesianChart.addSeries(chartSeries);
        }
    }
    return cartesianChart;
}
```

and the page's code:

```
<ui:repeat var="cartesianChartModel" value="#{analyzeMetricsController.cartesianChartModel}">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="panel panel-default col-lg-12" rendered="#{not empty cartesianChartModel}">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="panel-body panel-default">
            <p:lineChart id="chart" widgetVar="chart" 
                value="#{cartesianChartModel}" 
                legendPosition="ne" xaxisAngle="-45" zoom="true" 
                maxY="#{analyzeMetricsController.maxY}" 
                minY="#{analyzeMetricsController.minY}" 
                fill="#{analyzeMetricsController.filled}" 
                stacked="#{analyzeMetricsController.stacked}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

but only the last model graph is inserted. Moreover if I add this code under the tag

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="panel-body panel-default">
    <p:lineChart id="chart" widgetVar="chart" 
        value="#{cartesianChartModel}" 
        legendPosition="ne" xaxisAngle="-45" zoom="true" 
        maxY="#{analyzeMetricsController.maxY}" 
        minY="#{analyzeMetricsController.minY}" 
        fill="#{analyzeMetricsController.filled}" 
        tacked="#{analyzeMetricsController.stacked}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

only this last graph is inserted and  is ignored.

Comment: Maybe an id issue. Try this : <p:lineChart id="chart#{cartesianChartModel.id}" widgetVar="chart#{cartesianChartModel.id}" ... />

Comment: Thanks @Lamq. I was sure that I had tried to change the id but I didn't that. However the property id does not exist I use `<ui:repeat var="cartesianChartModel"
       value="#{analyzeMetricsController.cartesianChartModel}" varStatus="cartesianChartModelStatus">` and `<p:lineChart id="chart#{cartesianChartModelStatus.index}" widgetVar="chart#{cartesianChartModelStatus.index}"`

Comment: You're welcome. Think to validate the answser and welcome on stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an id issue, you need to do something like this :

```
<p:lineChart id="chart#{cartesianChartModel.id}" widgetVar="chart#{cartesianChartModel.id}" ... />
```

Cause you can't rendered two element with the same ID.

Comment: Doing some tests this morning I realized that the problem is not the id attribute but widgetVar attribute. Because the el expression is not  calculated in id attribute and the id in created xhtml page is the same for all linechart.